# how can I dispather socket request in my gateway?

Tags: sockets, gateway

I charge a gateway,which is responsible for all communications between in an out the company.
Now the gateway need support socket protocal to be called by some other system, and the socket requests should be dispathed to different APIs which are implement by hessian.

As I know, a socket request include ip,port,message body. Beside parse the socket message or use different port to match APIs. Is there other methods? for example, http request can use url's paths and headers to be dispathed.

sorry for my poor english...

Comment: Many gateways and routers support variety of methods for routing traffic, this is totally dependent on what hardware/software setup you use for your gateway (which you've failed to mention). Also, this is probably off topic as it doesn't involve programming or programming tools.

Comment: the gateway is pure software application, programming by java. We call it gateway because it adapt many rpc protocol, do some work like QoS, communication security and so on